# Apache, Create SSL Certficate for a IP adress

Tags: apache, ip, ssl-certificate

I am actually trying to create a test ssl certifcate for my webserver.
I started with [this tutorial](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html).

But when I try to create a certificate with the following command:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -sha1 -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj '/O=Company/OU=Department/CN=www.10.9.11.99/lebenmittel_test'
```

The following errors appears:

```
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
..............++++++
.................................++++++
writing new private key to 'server.key'
-----
end of string encountered while processing type of subject name element #3
problems making Certificate Request
```

I think the problem is, that I am trying to create a certificate for a IP address ... :/ 
I tried the same command with www.example.com and it worked.

Is there a way to create a certifcate for a IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that 'lebenmittel_test' is not a valid attribute syntax. Additionally, 'CN=www.10.9.11.99' is definitely dodgy for a CN.

Why not just assign a valid name for the CN, and then tweak your /etc/hosts file to point to the IP address using that name?